# How to send array elements to stdin of a command?

Tags: command-line, bash, redirect

I have a command that can receive a list of file paths, newline separated, from stdin. I have these file paths stored in an array. How should I send the array elements to the command?

I have used the following, but have a vague feeling that I'm not doing it efficiently:

```
files=("/first/file" "/second/file" "/some/directory" "/file/with spaces")
for i in "${places[@]}" ; do echo "$i" ; done | command ...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I prefer `printf`:

```
printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" | ...
```

You can also use `IFS` to join array elements using a character:

```
(IFS=$'\n'; echo "${array[*]}") | ...
```

The difference between `"${array[@]}"` and `"${array[*]}"` is that the former expands to the array elements as separate words, the latter expands to a single word formed by joining the array elements using the first character of `IFS`.

Comment: I had leaned toward `printf` because of `print0` from `find` making a null separated list, but forgot that it prints again when the arguments exceed the number of %s in the string. The IFS way is really interesting too, you've got my +1.

Comment: @Arronical if you got the files from `find`, the the default action uses newline as the separator

Comment: Oh sorry I'm being confusing, I hadn't got them from find, it had just made my brain think in the direction of `printf`.

Comment: I took your approach to loop over an array using gnu parallel: `printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" | parallel my_command {} $second_param_for_mycommand ` Having problems to get the $second_param_for_mycommand with `parallel my_command ::: "${array[@]}"`